# Getting Public Key for transaction in electrum

Tags: transactions, electrum, public-key

Liberty.me has asked purchasers to all pay into a single address, but then to email the "public key" of the transaction. What is the public key of the transaction? How would you find it in Electrum?

Comment: Transactions don't have public keys, only addresses do.

Answer (score -1):

I think what they're referring to is the address that you sent the bitcoin from. It sounds like they're probably manually validating the transactions so it couldn't hurt to also send them the link to the transaction on http://blockchain.info

Answer (score -1):

In the History tab, if you right click in a transaction you can see the details of that tx, then you can copy the Transaction ID (I think that is what you've been asked).

This is what is asked most of the times when having the payment method that way.